# I have defined my domain and problem in pddl for a logistic problem. I am very new in the field and i am currently struggling to generate a plan

Tags: google-ai-platform, planning

the Problem was defined in pddl as well. I am looking for a use friendly planner that I could use.online solver gave me this error:stderr:
FATAL:   container creation failed: mount /proc/self/fd/3->/var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session/rootfs error: while mounting image /proc/self/fd/3: failed to find loop device: could not attach image file to loop device: failed to attach loop device: could not open /dev/loop8: no such file or directory

stdout:

```
    (define (problem logistic-problem) (:domain logistic)
(:objects 
    location_1 location_2 - delivery-location
    item_1 item_2 item_3 - item
    order_1 order_2 - order 
    transport_1 transport_2 - transport
)

(:init
    (in-warehouse item_1)
    (in-warehouse item_2)
    (not(part-of-manufacturing item_3))
    (=(warehouse-quantity item_1) 80)
    (=(warehouse-quantity item_2) 10)
    (=(fixed-order-quantity item_1)10)
    (=(fixed-order-quantity item_2)10)
    (=(transport-capacity transport_1) 40)
    (=(transport-capacity transport_2) 80)
    (=(num-items-ordered item_2 order_2)40)
    (=(num-items-ordered item_2 order_1)20)
    (transport-available transport_1)
    (transport-available transport_2)
    


    ;todo: put the initial state's facts and numeric values here
)

(:goal (and
    (order-delivered item_1 location_1)
    (not(order-delivered item_2 location_2))
    ;todo: put the goal condition here
))

;un-comment the following line if metric is needed
;(:metric minimize (???))
)
```

Domain Definition

```
(define (domain logistic)
     (:requirements :duration-inequalities :equality :negative-preconditions :numeric-fluents :object-fluents :typing :fluents :conditional-effects :strips)

   
        order item delivery-location transport  quantity
    )
    (:constants
        perishable - item
        sensitive - item
        medical - item

    )

    (:predicates

        (in-warehouse ?i - item)
        (part-of-manufacturing ?i - item)
        (transport-available ?t - transport)
        (order-placed ?o - order)
        (supplier-order-placed ?o - order ?i - item)
        (scheduled-delivery ?o - order ?i - item)
        (place-waiting-list ?o - order)
        (delivery-location-same-area ?l - delivery-location ?i - item ?o - order)
        (order-delivered ?i - item ?l - delivery-location)
        (place-order-manufacturing ?i - item ?o - order)
        

    )
    (:functions
        (warehouse-quantity ?i - item)
        (num-items-ordered ?i - item ?o - order)
        (fixed-order-quantity ?i - item)
        (transport-capacity ?t - transport)
        (scheduled-items-quantity ?o - order ?i - item)
    )
    (:action place-order
        :parameters (?o - order ?i - item)
        :precondition ( in-warehouse ?i)
        :effect ( and

            (when
                (>= (warehouse-quantity ?i) (fixed-order-quantity ?i))
                (order-placed ?o)
            )
            (decrease
                (warehouse-quantity ?i)
                (num-items-ordered ?i))

            ;list of order sorted by priority,item ,location and quantity 

        )
    )

    (:action order-manufacturing
        :parameters (?i - item ?o - order)
        :precondition (and
            (not (in-warehouse ?i))
            (not(order-placed ?o))
            (part-of-manufacturing ?i)
        )
        :effect (place-order-manufacturing ?i ?o)
    )
    (:action order-supplier
        :parameters (?i - item ?o - order)
        :precondition (and
            (not (in-warehouse ?i))

            (not(place-order-manufacturing ?i ?o))
            (not(part-of-manufacturing ?i)))
        :effect (supplier-order-placed ?i ?o)

    )
    (:action schedule-delivery
        :parameters (?o - order ?t - transport ?i - item) ;sorted order list  ;list of transport(capacity)
        :precondition (and
            (transport-available ?t)
            (order-placed ?o)

        )
        :effect (and (decrease
                (transport-capacity ?t)
                (num-items-ordered ?i ?o)
                )
            (scheduled-delivery ?o ?i)
            (increase
                (scheduled-items-quantity ?o ?i)
                ( transport-capacity ?t))

            (when
                (not (transport-available ?t))
                (place-waiting-list ?o))

        )
        ;return a schedule list of orders and a waiting list

        ;

        ;update the totalquantity of scheduled item  items
        ;(decrease)available capacity for the available transport
        ;list of items tuple(item,quantity, location, order)
    )

    (:action delivery
        :parameters (?o - order ?i - item ?t - transport ?l - delivery-location ) ;list of schedule list of orders
        :precondition (and
            (scheduled-delivery ?o ?i)
            (place-waiting-list ?o)
        )
        :effect (and

            ( when(scheduled-delivery ?o ?i)
                (forall
                    (?o - order ?i - item)
                    (when
                        (<= (transport-capacity ?t)0)
                        (order-delivered ?i ?l)
                    )))

            (when
                (and (= ?i perishable) (> (transport-capacity ?t)0)  (delivery-location-same-area ?l  ?i  ?o))
                (order-delivered ?i ?l))
            (when
                (and (= ?i medical) (> (transport-capacity ?t)0) (delivery-location-same-area ?l  ?i  ?o))
                (order-delivered ?i ?l))
            (when
                (and (= ?i sensitive) (> (transport-capacity ?t)0)(delivery-location-same-area ?l  ?i  ?o) )
                (order-delivered ?i ?l))
        )

        ;delivered =true
        ;loop through the order and for each order set delivered to true

        ;universal quantify
    )
)
```